# question about "Homology fibrations and the group completion theorem"

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration, classifying-spaces, loop-spaces

In the paper [Homology fibrations and group completion theorem, McDuff-Segal,](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mcdsegal.pdf)
page 281 line 17-line 18:

we have a  fibre bundle $M_\infty\to (M_\infty)_M\to BM$ with $(M_\infty)_M$ constractible. In order to prove Proposition~1 (Group-Completion Theorem), is it necessary to apply Proposition~2 of the paper [Homology fibrations and group completion theorem, McDuff-Segal](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mcdsegal.pdf)? I noted that by applying Proposition 4.66, [Algebraic topology, A. Hatcher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf), I obtain that $\Omega BM$ is weak homotopy equivalent to $M_\infty$. Hence we do not need Proposition~2 of the paper [Homology fibrations and group completion theorem, McDuff-Segal](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mcdsegal.pdf) anymore. Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M_\infty\to (M_\infty)_M\to BM$ is not always a fiber bundle, not even a (Serre-)fibration. It is a homology fibration, which is a weaker notion.There will be no long exact sequence of homotopy groups, so you can't argue as in Hatcher's book.

Let me give you a general advise based on the type of questions you ask these days. I strongly recommend you to read Allen Hatcher's account on the group completion theorem in Appendix D of [his exposition of the Madsen-Weiss theorem](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/MW.pdf), before trying to fully understand the fantastic six pages of McDuff and Segal. Please notice that there are known some small mistakes in the paper, some of them mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109604/is-every-group-completion-map-an-acyclic-map#comment484770_109604). Compare [Martin Palmer and Jeremy Miller's](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4389) recent account of the group completion theorem, which does not have these issues.